# How do I pass C++ lambda function to another function?

Tags: c++, closures

```
auto xxx= [&radius](Vector3 pos)->float {
        SDF sdf;
        return sdf.Sphere(Vector3(pos.X, pos.Y, pos.Z), radius);
    };
```

calling

```
DensityPoint*** densityPoints2 = GetDensityData(dimensions, Vector3(), Vector3(), xxx);
```

on

```
DensityPoint*** Density::GetDensityData(Vector3 dimensions, Vector3 fractions, Vector3 offsets, float f(Vector3 pos))
{
```

And it says `...no suitable conversion function...`

When I remove the reference (closure) from lambda, it doesn't give the error.

Comment: See [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). Use [function objects](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional), so [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) with [lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). Provide some [mre] in your next question

Comment: Only a lambda without captures can be converted to a function see __ClosureType::operator ret(*)(params)()__ here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda  Also slight concern re `&radius` creating a dangling reference.

Comment: @RichardCritten "`&radius` creating a dangling reference*" - only if `xxx` is used after `radius` goes out of scope, which we can't determine from this limited snippet.